# SOLR Index & search on multiple datasource

Tags: mysql, search, solr, indexing, datasource

I have a problem to search on two dataSource. When I importAll, I see all my records import but when I search, I have in my results, only dataSource's 2 records.

In my data-config.xml :

```
<document>
   <entity name="one" dataSource="ds-1" query="SELECT * FROM artist">
     <field column="name" name="name" />
   </entity>

   <entity name="two" dataSource="ds-2" query="SELECT * FROM faqdata">
     <field column="thema" name="thema" />
   </entity>
</document>
```

And in my schema.xml :

```
<fields>
 <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
 <field name="slug" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
 <field name="name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="alt_name" type="text" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
 <field name="created_at" type="date" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
 <field name="updated_at" type="date" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
 <field name="thema" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />

 <field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

 <dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" multiValued="true" />   
</fields>

<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>  

<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>

<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>

<copyField source="name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="thema" dest="text"/>
```

What is problems?
Thank

Comment: how are the ids generated ???? do they overwrite the records from first datasource ?

Comment: how are the ids generated ???? how can i know how are generated?

Comment: are the id returned from the tables you are querying ?? as you have mentioned the id as a required field it is getting populated. Do you see id returned in the results ? if yes add string to the id to make it unique so that they don't overwrite each other

Comment: i've try : i've change my id on my first db by an other id which didn't exist on the second db. At the search, both of them are displayed. How can i avoid this overwrite ?

Comment: replied as answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ids in Solr needs to be unique.
If you insert Entities with the same Ids the previous record would get overwritten.
Solr does not update records. It deletes and reinserts the records.
If you want both the records, define a unique id.
e.g. Prepend Artist and faqdata to the id so that artists and faqdata don't overwrite each other.

SELECT A.*, 'ARTIST_' || ID PRIMARY_ID FROM ARTIST A

SELECT A.*, 'FAQDATA_' || ID PRIMARY_ID FROM FAQDATA A

and use PRIMARY_ID as the primary id and unique field.